Concerns about Job Security
I recently joined a company that specializes in Home Automation products, including a mobile app and associated hardware. The firmware is outsourced, while the mobile app and back-end systems are developed in-house. I'm replacing an engineer with extensive domain knowledge.
I'm currently facing a high-pressure situation with a critical project. We have a strict two-month deadline for a mobile app and hardware launch. The project is managed using a waterfall approach, with tasks assigned based on estimations and deadlines set by upper management, without sprints.
Sales have dropped, a major client has removed our product, and this project is crucial for mitigating potential profit losses by resolving hardware and app performance issues. There's significant pressure on our team, and job security seems tied to the success of this project.
I've observed some red flags: slow feedback from outsourced firmware testing is affecting our development speed, and there's tense communication from project managers all the way up to the C-suite. Given that I'm only a month into a six-month probation period, I'm concerned about my position if the project doesn't succeed.
Should I be worried about my job security, and should I be looking for another job? I feel slightly guilty for bailing, as I have good rapport with colleagues in my team and other departments.

It sounds like you already know the answers...

Based on your description, a critical path to success is the firmware, which your team is not responsible for, and there are concerns if the firmware testing will be successful. You can look for another job, and given you have a 2-month deadline, you will know by the end of the deadline if you will be successful. You also don't have to leave before the 2-month deadline, you can wait, until after you have more information.


Should I be worried about my job security, and should I be looking for another job?

Yes and yes. The company is having a major problems and they do not appear to be handling it well. If anything goes sideways, your head will be one of the first on the chopping  block. Not because of anything you have done but simply since you the most junior, still in probation and easy to fire.

I feel slightly guilty for bailing, as I have good rapport with colleagues in my team and other departments

No need. It's just business and I highly doubt that they would show any loyalty to you if money gets tight.
The one thing you SHOULD feel a bit guilty about is: how did you end up in that mess in the first place? Apparently you didn't see the warning signs when you interviewed for the job. I strongly recommend working on your job assessment skills to make sure your next job is long term sustainable. If you don't know how to do this, ask a separate question.

You describe a big project in which pretty everything is dysfunctional. That is probably there reason why "an engineer with extensive domain knowledge" left the company.
In your place, I would not allow dust to accumulate on my CV. Find a better job, before your colleagues find it :)
